# How to Merge files using For each activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using ADF to copy the files from a file server to Azure Blob storage. The files in the directory have the same structure without headers and I need to merge them to a single file in the Blob storage.

[image]

I created a ADF pipeline which uses get metadata to fetch the childItems and For each activity to loop through the files one by one

[image]

Inside the For each activity there is a copy data activity where I use the file name from the get metadata activity

[image]

In the sink setting, I use Merge files as the copy behaviour

[image]

When I execute the pipeline, the copy activity gets executed for 3 times and the file in the blob storage gets overwritten with the last file. How do I merge all the 3 files ?

I know we can use a wildcard pattern to select files. Suppose I have 3 files to begin with, when I run the get metadata activity and by the time the control comes to copy job activity and by this time if there is an addition of 4th file in the folder then with the wildcard pattern I will process all the 4 files and get metadata activity gives me the file names of the 3 files which I will use for archiving which is not right

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for each for this.  Just one copy activity that Marges all three files.

The trick would be to identify the source files using file path wildcards. if the requirement is to merge all file from source dataset, then merge behaviour in copy activity should be sufficient.

Comment: sorry had to copy paste the above scenario...I know we can use a wildcard pattern to select files. Suppose I have 3 files to begin with, when I run the get metadata activity and by the time the control comes to copy job activity and by this time if there is an addition of 4th file in the folder then with the wildcard pattern I will process all the 4 files and get metadata activity gives me the file names of the 3 files which I will use for archiving which is not right. And the files can come in any order so we cannot use the wild cards here

Comment: copy activity with merge behavior is still your best way to achieve your requirement, that is to merge source files in one destination file, you dont need foreach for that. for  handling newly arrived or updated files in the source , then depending on how source files are ingested into the file systems and file/folder structure you need to work on your strategy for identifying and handling newly arrived files, think about how files are partitioned and identified on the source, and how you wish to process changes, is it going to be a full merge every time something changes in the source!